# MySQL select values not in table from external set

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, select

I have a user table

id | name

1  | a

2  |  b

3  |  d

4  |  n

and i have a set from csv string ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

how can I query to return values not in user table

Expected result:   c, e

Thank you much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `not find_in_set(name, inList)`?

View more here [find in set](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

Comment: find_in_set will only return the location number.  What I want is the actual string which not in table